# How can I save custom evolution edits?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, ebean

I would like to continue to use automatic evolution generation with Play, but I would like to make edits on top of it.

Such as my logging table:

```
create table logging (
member_id                 bigint,
action_id                 smallint,
timestamp                 timestamp,
notes                     varchar(255))
;
```

I would like to add:

```
create index IX_logging on logging (member_id, action_id, timestamp);
```

But every time I make any modifications, it erases my changes.

What do I need to do to somehow use secondary evolution file that contains my modifications and keep auto generation? I don't think making a second `2.sql` would work, but I'm not sure. The documentation isn't very clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shortly: it is NOT possible, Ebean is not able to create differential evolutions and/or evolutions only for new models/fields, only thing you can do is creating them yourself.